# When are scripts inside etc/profile.d executed?

Tags: linux, centos, startup, init.d

I added some scripts from `root` inside `etc/profile.d` to execute at startup time. But when will these scripts be executed if I login into system as a non root user? I want to start LDAP-server at start-up time, independently from which user has first logged in.

I use CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Files in `/etc/profile.d/` are run when a user logs in](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/11.0/postlfs/profile.html) (unless you've modified `/etc/profile` to *not* do this) and are generally used to set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a script to be started during system startup, you need to use `chkconfig` after putting the script in `/etc/init.d` folder.

This has nothing to do with user login.

Comment: Sorry, I have mistake in my question: I putted some scripts inside `etc/profile.d`, not `/etc/init.d`.. My purpose is to run some .sh files when system is starting. Thanks.

Comment: @MyTitle: So, move your script to init.d folder and use `chkconfig` to add it to system startup.

Comment: Can you please say, who execute this scripts? This scripts executed automatically by root? I want to execute some .sh file where root doesn't have permissions.

Comment: @MyTitle: It will be executed as part of system startup process. If you want to execute it under different user, you may need to customize your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it at system startup you can add it to /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

Or make an init script with a suitable runlevel.

Comment: using chkconfig is much cleaner on centos

Comment: chkconfig require Sys-V compatible script. rc.local  not.